# Как сделать приоритет Console.Readline?

Tags: c#

Как сделать чтобы можно было писать команды в консоль в любой момент времени?
Например при выполнении Thread.Sleep(1000); я в консоль не могу написать команду, пока он не отработает. Нужно сделать чтобы ввод в консоль был с высоким приоритетом (работал поверх всего).

```
    IsWorking = true;
                while (IsWorking)
                {
             message =  Console.ReadLine();
                        if (message == Hello.FirstOrDefault(s => s == message))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Answer(0));
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);  //(это пример потраченного времени. Здесь мог бы находиться массив или что-то еще) на этом этапе ввод в консоль будет недоступен, а нужно чтобы в консоль можно было писать команды.
              else if (message == "Пока" || message == "До свидания")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Answer(1));
                        IsWorking = false;
                    }
              else
                    Console.WriteLine(Answer(3));
                        }
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000) блокирует не консоль, а ваш поток.

Comment: Это для примера, представь что там массив на 10мл элементов записывается.

Comment: Ну вам же уже писали в другом вашем вопросе: выполняйте длительные действия в другом потоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var menu = new Menu(Console.WriteLine, Console.ReadLine);
    while (menu.ShowCommands())
    {
        menu.ExecuteCommand();
    }
}

class Menu
{
    private readonly Action<string> _output;
    private readonly Func<string> _input;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action> _options;
    private Action _currentOption;
    private bool _isDone;

    public Menu(Action<string> output, Func<string> input)
    {
        _output = output;
        _input = input;

        _options = new Dictionary<string, Action>
        {
            ["_"] = () => InputError(),
            ["Пока"] = () => Exit(),
            ["Делай дело"] = () => DoWork()
        };

    }

    private void InputError()
    {
        _output("Неверная команда. Повторите ввод.");
        _output(string.Empty);
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        _output("Начинаю вычислять...");
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //что-то вычисляем здесь...
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        });
    }

    private void Exit()
    {
        _isDone = true;
        _output(string.Empty);
        _output("Выходим...");
        _output("Нажмите ввод");
        _input();
    }

    internal bool ShowCommands()
    {
        if (_isDone)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _output("Доступные команды:");
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var key in _options.Keys)
        {
            if (key.Equals("_"))
                continue;
            _output($"{++index}. {key}");
        }
        _output("Введите команду:");
        var input = _input();
        var optKey = _options.Keys.SingleOrDefault(k => k.StartsWith(input));
        if (optKey is null)
        {
            optKey = "_";
        }
        _currentOption = _options[optKey];
        return true;
    }

    internal void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        _currentOption();
    }
}
```